# need to delete old image name from table of database

Tags: php, mysql

hi2all i have tabel which contain 2 fields like that

---

|name| imags
**_*|*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

when user logined in my site i register it's name in session and when he upload his new photo

i want to delete it's old photo and sets his name to new photo how to do that ???

my code which insert each uploaded image in db is as following what i should add to my

```
$me=$_SESSION['logged-in'];


 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","register_form");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }



@mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO imgs (name, imags)
VALUES ('$me', '$filename')");



mysqli_close($con);
```

---

and here is my code to show it

```
  <?php




            $me=$_SESSION['logged-in'];
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","register_form");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT imags FROM  imgs where name LIKE '$me' ");


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
           $pathimg=$row['imags'];

          $d = dir("image");

    $entry = $d->read();
    /*while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
       echo "<li><img src=\"/ConnectMe/html/image/" . $entry . "\">" . $entry . "</li>";
    }

      */
      }

    mysqli_close($con);

echo"

<img width='50' height='60' src=\"/ConnectMe/html/image/$pathimg" . @$entry . "\">
";
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well you want to delete old table row containing currently logged in name before inserting new photo.

Change your INSERT statement to that lines of code.

Check whether there is a row in a table containing that name. If so, UPDATE that row with new photo. If not just insert new row with your INSERT statement.

This link could be helpful: [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM imgs WHERE name = '$me'");
if(mysqli_affected_rows() == 1) //it means that user uploaded a photo before
{
    $update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE imgs SET imgs = '$filename' WHERE name = '$me'");
    if(mysqli_affected_rows() == 1) //it means that UPDATE was successfull
    {echo 'Your photo was updated successfully';}
}
else
{
    @mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO imgs (name, imags) VALUES ('$me', '$filename')");
}
```

If you want to delete file from filesystem you should use [unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function giving previous path as a parameter.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: it worked but when i see database i see duplicated files i think the data stored 3 times any soultion?? here is shot
http://i.stack.imgur.com/ytVPb.png

Comment: If first `mysqli_affected_rows()` returns 0 it means that table doesn't have a row with given name and new row will be inserted.
You can maually check what you select statement returns using phpmyadmin.
There is also a simple option that will not permit inserting more rows with same name.
That means you have to add a unique index on that column.

Comment: That means you have to add a unique index on that column.
You can do it by viewing table structure and click icon with "U" inside 'action' column (depends on phpmyadmin version) or you can use SQL query to achieve that
`ALTER TABLE imgs ADD UNIQUE INDEX name_unique(name);`